# Unable to make HTTP REQUEST successfully from jmeter when on VPN

Tags: jmeter, postman, vpn, fiddler, connection-refused

I have a test plan created for my API testing in jmeter. The HTTP requests run successfully when i disconnect from my corporate VPN, but when i am connected to VPN, the HTTP request fails - `failed: Connection refused: connect` - *What could be causing Jmeter to work with VPN ?*

The same thing happened to my tests on Postman, but the problem got resolved after enabling this option in fiddler (Rules --> Automatically Authenticate). If i close my fiddler or stop capturing, the postman requests would also start to fail (This behavior is seen both on/off vpn). - *I am not sure how is Fiddler settings connected to postman.*

Have anyone experienced the same ? Please guide me with some solutions to try and make these tools work properly on VPN without any fiddler changes or dependencies.

I am on `Jmeter 5.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

As you are on corporate VPN, you need to add your corporate certificate to trust store.

Obtain the certificate first.
Add Certificate to Trust Store Command.

```
keytool -import -alias certificatename -keystore c:\java-se-8u40-ri\jre\lib\security\cacerts -file location to your certificate
```

This resolved the issue for me and was able to run jmeter on corporate vpn.

You can also refer too : [How to import a jks certificate in java trust store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700132/how-to-import-a-jks-certificate-in-java-trust-store)

Hope, this helps.